# Modify listbox from another class with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

I'm doing a GUI for a database through PyQt and Python. The main window (class Window) has a listbox where I put all my data, for this example I put "The program is working". Furthermore, The other window (class AddWin) help me to add new costumers to the database, but I couldn't modify the listbox from the class Addwin. I have the following code in my program and I would like to clean the listbox from the class AddWin, can you help me? or what is my mistake in the following code?

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        #Listbox 
        self.lista = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.lista.move(155,221)
        self.lista.resize(855,455)
        self.lista.addItem("The program is working")

class AddWin(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        main = Window()
        main.lista.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that code doesn't instantiate `AddWin` anywhere, so lista.clear is never called.

Your can test it by changing

```
window = Window()
```

to

```
window = AddWin()
```

---

**LAST EDITED 21 / 8 / 2014 12 : 42**

If your want to shard `QtGui.QListWidget` from `QtGui.QMainWindow` to `QtGui.QDialog`, Your can use pass value by reference to `QtGui.QDialog`.

Assume your `QtGui.QMainWindow` must have `QtGui.QDialog` (Or `AddWin`);

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        #Listbox 
        self.lista = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.lista.move(155,221)
        self.lista.resize(855,455)
        self.lista.addItem("The program is working")
        self.myAddWin = AddWin(self.lista, self) # <- Pass QListWidget to your class

class AddWin(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, refQListWidget, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.myRefQListWidget = refQListWidget
        self.myRefQListWidget.clear()
```